# PHP file chrashes server

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make a PayPal IPN file but the response won't be inserted into the database. After a little debugging i found that my function has one error but i don't know which one.

It seems that the following code is wrong, but i don't know why. It looks good to me. Am i doing something wrong?

```
<?php
function check_price($price, $id) {
  $valid_price = false;

  $sql = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `webc_products` WHERE id = '$id'");
  foreach ( $sql as $prod ) {
    $num = (float)$prod->amount;
    if($num == $price){
      $valid_price = true;
    }   
  }

  return $valid_price;
}

$a = check_price(0.01, 1);
?>
```

Also, i tried the code outside the function and somehow it works.

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled? If you cannot tell us what exactly the error is it would be very hard to tell you.

Comment: Is there anything in the server error logs?

Comment: Nope, but the page won't even display. I'm gettin: _Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://example.com/test/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly._

Comment: Enable error reporting first and ask later.

Comment: Sorry guys. I found the problem: $wpdb wasn't declared global inside the function. Thanx. :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're function is accessing the `$wpdb` object without actually having access to it (variable scope).
Either pass it as a parameter to your function (I'd recommend that) or declare it as global in your function.